# Turning wifi on cause my Laptop to freeze

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, laptop-repair

I have a **HP-G42 Laptop** with windows 10 installed, recently i came across new issues

- Turning WiFi on causes laptop to freeze including mouse and keyboard.
- Sometimes it freeze for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

Random freezes of the system are usually caused by buggy drivers or hardware faults.
Try to update all drivers, especially the WiFi driver, to their latest version.
If this does not help, contact your vendor. Some hardware could be defective.